# How can I create an ASP .NET MVC 5 solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I never used ASP.NET framework before.
I saw some tutorial videos of ASP .NET MVC 5, but when I create a new project of ASP .NET MVC with .NET framework 4.8, the project doesn't have a StartUp.cs like the tutorial videos.
Can you tell me why this happen? And also how can I have the startup class in my project?

**Edit:**

I added images of what I'm asking. I hope that you can help me.

- [How the project is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5yPj.jpg)
- [How the project has to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb6OI.png)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try to create an [ASP.NET Core MVC project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Maybe you create a wrong project type.... You can paste your solution photo.

Comment: I can't use ASP .NET Core MVC, it's a requirement to use ASP .NET Framework MVC 5.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you need ASP.NET Core project not Framework.
You can check [here](https://medium.com/net-core/asp-net-core-mvc-web-application-project-structure-3ccaa244fa66) project structure for asp.net core.